# Plot with callouts and arrows

Tags: plotting, labeling

All,

I am trying to create a graphic that looks like the follows:

[image: ListLine Plot with two functions and labels]

```
   f[x_] := 1*Exp[-x/2]*Sin[x];
   g[x_] :=  Exp[-x/2]*Cos[x];
   t1 = Table[i, {i, 0, 2*\[Pi], \[Pi]/12}];
   t2 = Table[i, {i, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/24}];

   data1 = Partition[Riffle[t1, f[t1]], 2];
   data2 = Partition[Riffle[t2, g[t2]], 2];
```

A custom function to extract max and min

```
minmaxCoords[dat_] := Module[{max, maxPos, min, minPos, fMin, fMax},
max = Max[dat[[All, 2]]]; 
maxPos = (First[Flatten[Position[#1, Max[#1]]]] &)[dat[[All, 2]]];
fMax = dat[[maxPos]][[1]];

min = Min[dat[[All, 2]]]; 
minPos = (First[Flatten[Position[#1, Min[#1]]]] &)[dat[[All, 2]]];
fMin = dat[[minPos]][[1]];  
{{fMin, min}, {fMax, max}}]


plot1 = ListLinePlot[
Callout[data1, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(Min\)]\)", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(Max\)]\)"}, minmaxf1, 
 CalloutMarker -> "Circle", Appearance -> "CurvedLeader"]
, Frame -> { {True, False}, {True, True}}
, FrameLabel -> {{"f(x)", "y"}, {"x", ""}}
, FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}
, GridLines -> {{First@First@minmaxCoords[data1], 
  First@Last@minmaxCoords[data1]}, None}
, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Red, Dotted]
, Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}
, PlotStyle -> Lighter@Red
, ImageSize -> Large
, AspectRatio -> 0.4
];

plot2 = ListLinePlot[
Callout[data2, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(Min\)]\)", 
First@minmaxg1, CalloutMarker -> "Circle", 
Appearance -> "CurvedLeader", LeaderSize -> {20}]
, Frame -> { {False, True}, {False, False}}
, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}
, FrameLabel -> {{"f1", "g(x)"}, {"x", ""}}
, GridLines -> {{First@First@minmaxg1}, None}
, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Blue, Dotted]
, PlotStyle -> Lighter@Blue
, ImageSize -> Large
, AspectRatio -> 0.4
];

 plot3 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}], 
 Arrow[{{First@First@minmaxf1, 0.1}, {First@Last@minmaxf1, 0.1}}], 
 Text["\[CapitalDelta]f", {2.5, 0.12}]}];
```

I try to plot:

```
  Overlay[{Show[plot1, plot3], plot2}]
```

[image]

I would really appreciate help on the following items:

- Callout style
- Callouts not appearing for red curve
- Text on top of arrow

Comment: Sorry, should `minmaxf1`, and `minmaxg1` be obvious?

Comment: Looks like that got truncated when I copied and pasted the code. I added those definitions...

Comment: Why don't you post the solution as an answer?  It is okay to self-answer.

Comment: Indeed, I would roll back the edits so that there's an actual question here.

Comment: Rolled back Edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the answer

All,

```
   f[x_] := 1*Exp[-x/2]*Sin[x];
   g[x_] :=  Exp[-x/2]*Cos[x];
   t1 = Table[i, {i, 0, 2*\[Pi], \[Pi]/12}];
   t2 = Table[i, {i, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/24}];

   data1 = Partition[Riffle[t1, f[t1]], 2];
   data2 = Partition[Riffle[t2, g[t2]], 2];
```

A custom function to extract max and min

```
minmaxCoords[dat_] := Module[{max, maxPos, min, minPos, fMin, fMax},
max = Max[dat[[All, 2]]]; 
maxPos = (First[Flatten[Position[#1, Max[#1]]]] &)[dat[[All, 2]]];
fMax = dat[[maxPos]][[1]];

min = Min[dat[[All, 2]]]; 
minPos = (First[Flatten[Position[#1, Min[#1]]]] &)[dat[[All, 2]]];
fMin = dat[[minPos]][[1]];  
{{fMin, min}, {fMax, max}}]


minmaxf1 = minmaxCoords[data1];
minmaxg1 = minmaxCoords[data2];


plot1 = ListLinePlot[
Callout[data1, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(max\)]\)", 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(min\)]\)"}, {Above, Below}, 
CalloutMarker -> "\[EmptyCircle]", CalloutStyle -> Gray, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Italic], Background -> White, 
Frame -> False, FrameMargins -> 4
]
, Frame -> { {True, False}, {True, True}}
, FrameLabel -> {{"f(x)", "y"}, {"x", ""}}
, FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}
, GridLines -> {{First@First@minmaxCoords[data1], 
  First@Last@minmaxCoords[data1]}, None}
, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Red, Dotted]
, Ticks -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}
, PlotStyle -> Lighter@Red
, ImageSize -> Large
, AspectRatio -> 0.5
];

plot2 = ListLinePlot[
Callout[data2, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(min\)]\)", Below, 
CalloutMarker -> "\[EmptyCircle]", CalloutStyle -> Gray, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Italic], Background -> White, 
Frame -> False, FrameMargins -> 4]
, Frame -> { {False, True}, {False, False}}
, FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}
, FrameLabel -> {{"f1", "g(x)"}, {"x", ""}}
, GridLines -> {{First@First@minmaxg1}, None}
, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Blue, Dotted]
, PlotStyle -> Lighter@Blue
, ImageSize -> Large
, AspectRatio -> 0.5
];

plot3 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}], 
Arrow[{{First@First@minmaxf1, 0.1}, {First@Last@minmaxf1, 0.1}}], 
Text["\[CapitalDelta]f", {2.5, 0.12}]}];

Overlay[{Show[plot1, plot3], plot2}]
```

[image]